# Coriander in a blueberry ice-cream?

Tags: spices, ice-cream

I'm a beginner, and trying to follow [this](http://cookingfortwo.about.com/od/desserts/r/blueberryicecrm.htm) recipe.

Along the lines, it's said that we should add **coriander**. I'm still a beginner, but I find it weird to add coriander into an ice-cream recipe. Please explain to me why should I add coriander? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add coriander, it should be because you agree with Mr. Weeks's assertion that it has a particular affinity with blueberry. Freshly ground coriander has a vibrant citrusy aroma, and (though I haven't tried it), I can see how it would go well in blueberry ice cream. I've found that sometimes a single flavor can be a little monotonous, and the coriander can bring some fun to the party. Give it a shot and see what you think.

Comment: I agree both with your reasoning and your evaluation of coriander. It sounds like it would be very interesting with blueberry. Keep in mind that ice cream flavorings need to be stronger than other dishes because the cold deadens the taste buds.

Comment: I also find that rosemary is very nice with blueberry. That might be a fun substitution.

Answer (score 1):

just as another example, another interesting pairing with blueberry is ground cardamom.